# Is the allowance by parents a legitimate source of income to enter the Schengen area?

Tags: visas, schengen, proof-provenance-of-funds

I don't have any job nor have any job history; my source of income is only the monthly allowance by my mother.

At least it is enough to meet the minimum threshold of financial requirement to enter the Schengen area in some countries.

In this case, as long as I pick up a country that stipulates the low minimum threshold to enter, is the allowance by parents considered a legitimate source of income?

I can enter the Schengen area without holding the visa, and I'm not minor, for your information.

Comment: Yes, although border officers could in theory ask you to prove that your mother has come by the money she gave you legitimately.

Comment: @phoog Is there any evidence or maybe could you eleborate it as an answer?

Comment: If you do not need a visa, it might be easiest to have a few hundred € in cash while you cross the border. That and your passport should answer all questions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is, as long the funds are legally obtained by the source (your parents) and as long as it meets the given financial threshold.

You are being supported by your family, not uncommon or unusual, and the monies are really gifts, rather than employment income.

What you might want to carry is evidence that the flow of funds is constant and steady, as well as that you have access to other financial resources, such as credit card or a line of credit at your bank.

Too, it might be wise to have at the ready clarifying information, such as your mother's bank statement and the standing order to disburse money into your account.

Comment: Do you have any sources to prove it?

Comment: @Blaszard look at provenance of funds, here and elsewhere.